# ¿Como guardar imagen en carpeta de servidor con php?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo mi codigo de registro de usuario de la siguiente manera, con lo cual se puede ingresar una imagen a la base de datos y se crea una carpeta con el ultimo ID de registro para llevar un mejor control de usuarios.

Mi codigo de ejecucion de PHP es el siguiente

```
include("conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST["registro"])) {

    $file = $_FILES['profile_image'];
    $filename = $file['name'];
    $filetype = $file['type'];
    $filetmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last_name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $password_encrypt = sha1($password);
    $about = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['about']);
    $sqlemail = "SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";
    $resultadoemail = $conn->query($sqlemail);
    $filas = $resultadoemail->num_rows;
    if ($filas > 0) {
        echo "<script>
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                text: 'Correo ya registrado, favor de utilizar otro.',  
                });
            </script>";
    } else {
        //Insertar informacion de usuario
        $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO members(name,last_name,email,password,profile_image,phone,about) VALUES('$name','$last_name','$email','$password_encrypt','$filename','$phone','$about')";
        $resultadoinsert = $conn->query($sqlinsert);
        $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
        $ruta = 'storage/' . $last_id . '/';
        $archivo = $ruta . $filename;

        //Validar registro
        if ($resultadoinsert > 0) {

            if (!file_exists($ruta)) {
                mkdir($ruta);
            }
            if (!file_exists($archivo)) {
                $resultadofoto = move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $archivo);
                if ($resultadofoto) {
                    echo "<script>
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: 'success',
                                text: 'Foto guardada correctamente.',  
                            });
                        </script>";
                } else {
                    echo "<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        text: 'Error al guardar.',  
                        });
                    </script>";
                }
            }
            echo "<script>
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                text: 'Miembro registrado correctamente.',  
                });
            </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                text: 'Error al registrar.',  
                });
            </script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Y mi formulario de HTML es el siguiente

```
<div id="register" class="p-0 modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="register" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-slideout" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content full">
            <div class="modal-header" data-dismiss="modal">
                <i class="icon-close fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 align-self-center">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 p-0 pb-3">
                                <h2>Registro</h2>
                                <p>¿Ya tengo cuenta? <a href="#" class="primary-color" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sign">Ingresar</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div id="content-profile-image" class="avatar d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 avatar-profile" style="position:relative;">
                                <div class="avatar-container">
                                    <input id='modal_profile_image2' type='file' hidden onchange="signupModalCrop(this)" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg" name="profile_image" />
                                    <img src="assets/images/default_profile.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-fluid shadow select-file cursor-pointer" id="modal-profile-image" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <label style="text-align: center;">Ingresa tu foto.</label>
                            <br>
                            <div class="col-md-6 p-0 input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" name="name" required> &nbsp;
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 p-0 input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido" name="last_name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 p-0 input-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" name="email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 p-0 input-group">
                                <input type="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono" name="phone" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 p-0 input-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" required>&nbsp;
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 p-0 input-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 p-0 input-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Mi semblanza" name="about" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 p-0 input-group align-self-center">
                                <button class="btn primary-button" name="registro">REGISTRARME</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Al momento de ejecutar el codigo el nombre de la imagen si se guarda en la base de datos pero no se crea el directorio y al momento de ejectuar el move_uploaded_file, manda directamente al error y no se guarda ninguna imagen.

Comment: ¿A qué error te refieres y cuál es el mensaje de error exactamente?

Comment: Al momento de ejecutar el if de $resultadofoto manda directamente a este else
else {
                    echo "<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        text: 'Error al guardar.',  
                        });
                    </script>";
                }

Comment: No conviene depurar a ciegas y mezclar código JS en contexto PHP es una práctica que deberías evitar. Intenta mostrar en el mensaje de error el contenido de `$_FILES["profile_image"]["error"]` para saber cuál es el motivo del fallo, o bien revisa el log de errores. Este código podría estar fallando por diversos motivos.

Comment: Hola mi amigo, porque no intentas agregar la variable ['file'] para subir la imagen. $_FILES['profile_image'] -> $_FILES['file']['profile_image'] con esto lo mejor funcione tu codigo